# Delaying function return until Ajax request completes

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm writing a simple utility to handle the numerous JSON calls I have to make in my app, but the problem with the readJson function below is that it completes before the inner function that gets the Ajax has got the data, so it returns undefined. Can anyone point me to an existing answer to this issue, or offer any advice on how to better structure this function so that it doesn't return until the Ajax request is complete?

```
json_manager = { 
    thisJson:'',
    readJson:function(theFileName, thePathName) {

        var theUrl=(thePathName+theFileName);
        $.getJSON(theUrl).done(function(theJSON) { 
                json_manager.thisJson=theJSON;
        });
        return(json_manager.thisJson)
    },
        //more functions 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a classic asynchronous problem. What's happening is the `$.getJSON` call doesn nothing more than setup the call to the server. It doesn't actually execute the call until the currently executing function returns control back to the browser.

In this situation, you have to structure your code to *tell* where the data goes, not *ask* for the data.

Something like this:

```
json_manager = { 

    readJson:function(theFileName, thePathName, callback) {

        var theUrl=(thePathName+theFileName);
        $.getJSON(theUrl).done(callback);

    },
        //more functions 
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
json_manager.readJson('file', 'path', function(data) {
   // do something with the returned json
});
```

This way, you're providing the `readJson` function with instructions on what to do with the data it gets from the server.

Comment: Thank you, rossipedia - worked perfectly - and an excellent explanation - I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can serialize things so that the ajax call finishes before the function returns is by making the ajax call synchronous.  And, that is NOT recommended because it often creates a seriously bad user experience for the end-user where the browser is locked up and not processing events during your ajax call.  Do not do it that way.

Other than that, the "A" in AJAX stands for asynchronous and you need to learn to program in asynchronous fashion using callbacks to carry out the work that needs the result from the AAX call.  Because Ajax is normally asynchronous, your `readJson()` function will return BEFORE the ajax call is complete.  Thus, you cannot return the result of the ajax call in that function.

To restructure your code to work with asynchronous ajax, you must move all the work that needs the result from the `$.getJSON()` into a callback and call that callback function with the result as an argument from the success/completion handler of the ajax call.

You could do that like this:

```
json_manager = { 
    thisJson:'',
    readJson:function(theFileName, thePathName, successHandlerFn) {

        var theUrl=(thePathName+theFileName);
        $.getJSON(theUrl).done(function(theJSON) { 
                successHandlerFn(theJSON);
        });
    },
        //more functions 
}
```

Comment: Thanks - yes, I understand the asynch issue - just didn't have a way to work around it - I'll check this out too - looks like a similar solution to the one I accepted so +1 :)